# SQL SERVER - GROUP BY Condition (When data is not present)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a huge table with the following data:

```
+----+-------+-----------+------------+
| Id | KeyId | Condition |  DateTime  |
+----+-------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |     1 |         0 | 2020-01-13 |
|  2 |     1 |         1 | 2020-01-14 |
|  3 |     1 |         0 | 2020-01-15 |
|  4 |     2 |         0 | 2020-01-13 |
|  5 |     2 |         0 | 2020-01-14 |
|  6 |     3 |         0 | 2020-01-15 |
|  7 |     3 |         1 | 2020-01-14 |
|  8 |     4 |         0 | 2020-01-15 |
|  9 |     4 |         0 | 2020-01-14 |
+----+-------+-----------+------------+
```

What I need is search in this table for some rows with the following conditions:

- Grouping rows find KeyId
- Get the KeyId where there is no `Condition = 1` (All conditions are `false`)
- Get the row of `MAX(DateTime)`
- Get the Id of that row.
- Result desired: Id of the rows.

For e.g., in the above example the Query will find:

`Groups 2 and 4` because they don't have `Condition in 1`
And Finally the `Id 5 and 8` because are the MAX(DateTime) of that groups.

The result desired is:

```
+----+
| Id |
+----+
|  5 |
|  8 |
+----+
```

I'm stuck in the very first thing because for begin, I can't even group with the condition!

```
SELECT Id FROM (
SELECT fieldsgroupedby FROM MyTable WHERE Condition = 0 GROUP BY KeyId
) grp
```

Any help/tip/comment/question will be really preciated.

Comment: If you want to group by you can not select *.  You have to either select the column and include it in the group by or do an aggregate function (like count or sum) on any column not included in the group by.

Comment: Yes @Brad sorry! It was a dummy SQL just for the e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytical function as follows:

```
select * from 
(select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by keyid order by datetime desc) as rn,
       count(case when condition = 1 then 1 end) over (partition by keyid) as cnt1
  from your_table t) t
 where rn = 1 and cnt1 = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when condition = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by key) as num_condition,
             row_number() over (partition by key order by datetime desc) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where num_condition > 0 and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I like the idea about the sum! Didn't think it. But about partition I have to study this, didn't know about this. Remembers me LinQ Group By. Thanks a lot Gordon!